# Дешифрование пароля на бэкэнде

Tags: perl, шифрование

Доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с такой задачей. Необходимо зашифровать пароль на JS (шифрую с помощью JSEncrypt RSA) и расшифровать его на бэкенде в Perl (использую модуль use Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA). На бэкэнде ловлю пароль в переменную $password и далее пытаюсь расшифровать вот так:

```
my $rsa = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->generate_key(2048);
my $keyFile = "priv.pem";
my $pubfile = "pub.pem";
my $string_Key = read_file($keyFile);
my $string_pub = read_file($pubfile);
my $rsa_pub = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_public_key($string_pub);
my $rsa_priv = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_private_key($string_Key);
$rsa_pub->use_pkcs1_padding();
$rsa_priv->use_pkcs1_padding();
#my $pw = 'vGrkY9cgVFgNrJR7RdYVjNDYlHptKRXA0hPjqset+ZOTLCpBOd9hmYUeYH7KFmc7ZA0ifC8BgmDMOlimpW2RhMJRWeg2xfDVk6Eo0lMkQUjbVh0PrOoW+JQIxxef8jtP9aBF1MKiWprG6Nxi8TMtLIo4NW3FM2dAy4CVNU9hY3E=';
my $decryptpass = $rsa_priv->decrypt(decode_base64($password));
```

Если использую пароль пришедший с фронта ($password) и пытаюсь расшифровать выходит ошибка RSA.xs:202: OpenSSL error: pkcs decoding error. Провел эксперимент и вставляю сюда **decrypt(decode_base64($password))** зашифрованный пароль из переменной $pw и все замечательно расшифровывает и выводит без ошибок. Подскажите пожалуйста чем ему может не нравиться пароль переданный через переменную в первом варианте?

Получаю пароль следующим образом:

```
my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $username = $cgi->param("username");
my $password = $cgi->param("password");
```

Он прилетает с фронта через get-запрос.

Comment: Вы на консоль отобразите то, что получили и ,вероятно, можно будет увидеть.

Comment: вывожу через print $password; то, что пришло, копирую, потом вставляю это в ввиде текста в переменную my $pw = 'вставляю значение', а ее уже вот сюда decrypt(decode_base64($pw)); и все работает. А вот если напрямую, то нет, ошибка. До меня никак не доходит чем может отличаться формат в двух этих случаях, что приводит к проблеме...

Comment: а как Вы $password получаете - кусок кода добавьте

Comment: Опенссл хочет контейнер pkcs, или настройте его на работу без контейнера или изобразите pem через ------ BEGIN

Comment: @Виктор, ответил на Ваш вопрос в своем сообщении.

Comment: @eri , по поводу контейнера, Вы имеете ввиду файлы с ключами? Если так, то они прописаны my $keyFile = "priv.pem"; и лежат в директории проекта. Сами ключи работают т.к если явно указывать, то что нужно расшифровать my $pw = 'vGrkY9cgVFgNrJR7RdYVjNDYlHptKRXA0hPjqset+ZOTLCpBOd9hmYUeYH7KFmc7ZA0ifC8BgmDMOlimpW2RhMJRWeg2xfDVk6Eo0lMkQUjbVh0PrOoW+JQIxxef8jtP9aBF1MKiWprG6Nxi8TMtLIo4NW3FM2dAy4CVNU9hY3E='; то проблем не возникает.

Comment: Может надо ещё: use URI::Encode;
my $uri     = URI::Encode->new( { encode_reserved => 0 } );
my $decoded = $uri->decode($password);

Comment: @Виктор, попробовал сделать так  
use URI::Encode;  
my $uri = URI::Encode->new( { encode_reserved => 0 } );  
my $decoded = $uri->decode($password);  
print $decoded;  
my $decryptpass = $rsa_priv->decrypt(decode_base64($decoded));  
Та же ошибка... Причем печатаю перед этим $decoded; он в том же формате что и в переменной  my $pw. Вообще не понятно, что ему ещё нужно.. То что распечаталось из $decoded вставялю напрямую сюда decrypt(decode_base64(........)); и все работает.

Comment: @chevy скорее всего вам не нужно делать `decode_base64` как вы пишите выше `то проблем не возникает` (если именно это придет с фронта так как это и есть base64)

Comment: @DaniilLoban, пробовал убрать decode_base64 получаю другую ошибку RSA.xs:202: OpenSSL error: data greater than mod len  :((

Comment: а Вы можете добавить в ответ что именно получаете с клиента?

Comment: Вот это уходит с клиента как get-запрос: **username=ad&password=SjI1oEpkewAPtqcnPCq4AQ18dkpHtbzgAUB6KP1XHK/fQKIt+ecQnWV7yT17pMAnxQJiVu43/4zJeyjyPxSY+jXPFM3F06nM8FNfwFcaUbWsNif8CH+Wo3M+r0ge0ey35z1aXkgDXkvmh39Ag7F4lLpXyiBhadTnAfrsZR7944k=&_=1665990568910**, если распечатать сразу то что пришло на бэкенд в переменную my $password = $cgi->param("password");, то получится тоже самое значение, что и выше только без &_=1665990568910

Comment: Тогда не понятно как не расштфровывается пароль?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В пароле есть плюс. Многие хттп движки заменяют плюс на пробел потому что многие браузеры заменяют пробел на плюс. (Сейчас уже на %20, но rfc осталось)

Делай экранирование на клиенте.

П.С. таже проверь знаки = и /.

П. П. С. Не используй  GET для авторизации - это не безопасно даже с шифрованием.

Comment: Вы оказались правы!!! Огромнейшее спасибо! Внимательно посмотрел сейчас на то что приходит уже в бэкенд, и действительно + из строки зашифрованного пароля исчезают, а вместо них пробел! Слэши и равно переваривает без потерь. По поводу GET это пока в режиме тестов, на боевом проекте будет обязательно post. Подскажите пожалуйста, а как можно реализовать экранирование? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Хотя думаю можно в бэкенде менять пробелы на + попробовать.

Comment: Галочку поставьте)

Comment: Сделано) спасибо ещё раз :)